# How to disable 'Pause before potential out-of-memory crash' in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

My application is expected to store large string (>10M) in one variable. While debugging other issue in network tab, I don't want Chrome DevTools to pause on such memory increase. Is there way to disable such check? Chrome parameter or DevTools settings?

Comment: There's no such option.